# MATLAB: deleting elements from multi-level cell

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, for-loop, cell

I've got a large multi-level cell and I'm trying to delete parts of it within a for loop but can't get past "Error: The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment."
Have tried a few versions and keep hitting the same error.

```
for i=1:length(List{1}{17}{imagenum})
     if List{1}{17}{imagenum}(i)>1
          List{1}{17}{imagenum}(i)=[];
     end
end
```

Separate question: When I delete parts of a cell/anything within a for loop, is there a standard/smart way of making sure the for loop stays on track? I've been using a variable to keep track of deletions but I'm assuming there's a smarter way of doing this:

```
deletions=0;

for i=1:length(List{1}{17}{imagenum})
     if List{1}{17}{imagenum}(i-deletions)>1
          List{1}{17}{imagenum}(i-deletions)=[];
          deletions=deletions+1;
     end
end
```

Comment: can i see the whole code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assign List{1}{17}{imagenum} to a:

```
a = List{1}{17}{imagenum};
```

Is 'a' cell or array? If it is array:

```
for i = numel(a):-1:1
    if a(i)>1, a(i) = []; end
end
```

Easier way should be:

```
a(a>1) = [];
```

If it is cell:

```
for i = numel(a):-1:1
    if a{i}>1, a(i) = []; end 
end
```

General rule: when you delete items in a loop, you start from the end, not the beginning.